# C code ENCODER! (arrays) (nested loops) (fgets) (syntax?)

Tags: c, nested, fgets

```
int i,j,k;
char key[5], input[5], word[7], output[7];

printf("Enter key:\n");
fgets(input, 5, stdin);

printf("Enter word:\n");
fgets(word, 7, stdin);
                                          //I am trying to store two
for (i = 0; i<7; i++) {                   //user-inputted arrays and then
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++) {               //do stuff with them. Fails before
        if (word[i] == key[j]) {          //I even get to the for loop.
            output[i] = input[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so basically this is the main portion of a program which is supposed to take in two arrays, a secret "key" and a word, composed of 5 and 7 characters respectively, and then by comparing the user-inputted key with a static, hidden key, spit out a NEW translated word which consists of different characters imposed by the user-inputted "key."

Anyways, the function is more-or-less not important because I can't even get my program off the ground! I am new to the fgets() function and am more or less poking around in the dark. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: `comparing the user-inputted key with a static,` not getting? and so far you doing right.

Comment: Well like in english if the user-inputted key is "def" and the static key is "abc", then the word "bac" becomes "edf"

Comment: from your code you comparing key with word means `word` is given by user rifht?

Comment: Yes! I'm so sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: Basically, I go through the user-inputted "word" array and match it with the specific static array, which consists of 5 different set char values. If there is a match, then I take the corresponding secret "key" array and throw it into an output array, which I then print out.

Comment: Did you use a debugger and/or `printf()` to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, if and if not I run a printf() function through my output array, the entire program aborts after I input my first 5 characters! i.e., I enter "rbcda", program returns "Enter word" and then ends immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `fgets` is only reading partial input is because the buffer too small. You need to increase the buffer size. Below is working code And what is the content of `input[]`
array?

```
void main()
{
    int i,j,k,n;
    char key[64], input[64], word[64], output[64];

    printf("Enter key:");
    fgets(input, sizeof(key), stdin);

    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';

    printf("Enter word:");
    fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);

     word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';
                                              //I am trying to store two
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++) {                   //user-inputted arrays and then
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++) {               //do stuff with them. Fails before
            if (word[i] == key[j]) {          //I even get to the for loop.
                output[i] = input[j];
            }
        }
    }   

    printf("%s\n",output);
}
```

Comment: SORRY for the late response, it was nearly 3AM and I had to hit the sack!

Comment: Thanks for responding! The content of the input[] array is the user inputted "key" while the content of the key[] array is the "static" key provided by the coder, annoying, I know ;_;

Comment: This solved the issue described in the comment 100%. I think I understand fgets() a little better now. Thanks again for your help. Do you think you could explain the lines "inputs[strlen(intput)-1] = '\0';"?

Comment: here `\0` is a sentinel value that indicates the end of the string means `inputs[strlen(intput)-1] = '\0'` append null char after input array string.